# What is difference between massage authentication and entity authentication?

Tags: authentication, entity, message

Message authentication (sometimes called data origin authentication) is the assurance that a given entity was the original source of the received data. Entity authentication (or user authentication) is the assurance that a given entity is involved and currently active in a communication session.

I know that can anyone give me any Difference Table?